# How do I find a compatible non-brand-name replacement adapter?

Tags: laptop, power-supply, asus-laptop

What techniques are useful for finding replacement electronic parts such as a laptop adapter. In my case, I am looking for an  inexpensive compatible replacement adapter/cord for my Asus N550JV-CN191H laptop, but general tips would be useful.

I'm not looking for exact answers or product links, but for a techniques to find a match.

How do I go about finding a compatible adapter online?

[image: Adapter]

[image: Plug]

Comment: You can just search ADP-120RH B and find results like http://www.my-adaptor.com/adp-120rh-b-m-43773.html

Comment: Right, but that's expensive. I am looking for a compatible adapter which may not have the same model number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The critical factors are voltage, amperage, and the plug that goes into the computer's charging jack.  Your 19V is pretty common, but most newer 19V supplies have lower current -- but what you need is available (I bought a 19V, 90W supply recently for around $10).

First, you need to determine the precise dimensions of the round plug that goes into the computer.  You can often get this information by Googling for "(computer model) power supply" or "(computer model) charger" and reading into the descriptions; you're looking for something like "2.5 mm x 5.5 mm" (that's the size on the one I bought for a 2002 Presario 700; yours is probably different).  Then search eBay and Google for power supplies with 19V, 120W (Watts are more commonly given than amps), and look through the listings for the plug dimensions you found and/or a mention of compatibility with your computer model.  Worth noting, higher power at the right voltage is perfectly fine, but lower power won't do the job, at least under some conditions (may charge the battery when the machine is off, but may not run the machine on external power).

Power levels this high won't be common (current 19V supplies are usually 65W), but should still be available.

Comment: Thank you. 

The shape of the socket on the other side of the adapter -- into which I plug the connector which also connects to the wall-- is also relevant, right? This one has a threeahole structure. What is the official spec name for that?

Comment: There are a couple standards for the mains cord; they can be had for a few dollars at any computer store (but it's likely it'll be included with the power supply; it was on mine).  If it's three wire, it'll be either a standard computer cord, or a "Mickey Mouse" appliance cord.